# Load config in the global window object

Tags: reactjs, config

I would like to load a configuration file to be used as a global object in various parts of the application.
I do not want to import because I want to keep separate from the bundle.js to be able to change it in the future without touching the app.

I came with this solution, and it works, it is correct? Can I encounter problems attaching the configuration to the window object?

// index.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="appconfig.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="myAppBundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
```

...................

// appconfig.js

```
var GlobalAppConfig = (function () {
      return {
          pictures: "https://www.example.com/pictures",
          videos: "https://www.example.com/videos",
        }
})();
```

.......................

// App.js

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                pictures: window.GlobalAppConfig.pictures
                videos: window.GlobalAppConfig.videos
            }

      }
```

Comment: why not use environment variables?

Comment: the app will be published on a webserver as static html and js files and I want to be able to change the configuration as I need

Comment: Yeah. most web servers allow you to set env vars that becomes available in the browser's process.env object here is a sample with nginx https://medium.com/comparethemarket/environment-configuration-with-react-nginx-2444e1f11a4c

Answer (score 0):

A drawback to this technique is that `window` may not be available in every context, such as a test environment.

Environmental variables would be a conventional solution. You could define them at build time (assuming a Yarn build step):

```
$ PICTURES_URL='https://www.example.com/pictures' yarn build
```

Then in your code:

```
const picturesURL = process.env.PICTURES_URL || '';
```

Rebuild after changing the environmental variable.